# complete list of poi-types in Germany

Tags: openstreetmap, linux, point-of-interest

look for a complete list of  poi-types

I use foursquare because it contains a lot of POIs. 
Which database do you use when you need a point of interest in North America?
Which database you use for Pois in Europe?

is this full & complete: https://github.com/MorbZ/OsmPoisPbf/blob/master/poi_types.csv

Answer (score 3):

There is no limit for the number of different POIs in OSM. The most common types are listed in the [map features](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_features) wiki page as well as on [taginfo](http://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/keys). But every contributor is [allowed to define new types](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Any_tags_you_like) by introducing new [tags](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags). Hence there are unlimited different POIs available and a complete list cannot exist.

Please ask a new your question and tell us what you actually want to achieve.